# Parsing Folders and Subfolders recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have the following file/folder structure

```
Start Folder
+-Sub1
| +-SubSub1
| +-File1 (100 byte)
+-Sub2
| +-File2 (200 byte)
+-Sub3
| +-File3 (300 byte)
| +-File4 (400 byte)
+-Sub4
  +-File5 (500 byte)
  +-SubSub2
    +-File6 (600 byte)
```

I need to convert this into a file of a specific format consisting of 'blocks' with the following requirements. Each block consists of a 20byte header. In each block header the size (header + data) is stored. A folder block has the file blocks and its subfolders blocks as data.

Example:

```
File6 Block = 620 bytes (20 header + 600 data)
SubSub2 Block = 640 bytes (20 header + 620 File6 Block)
File5 Block = 520 Bytes (20 header + 500 data)
Sub4 Block = 1180 bytes (20 header + 520 File5 Block + 640 SubSub2 Block)
Sub3 Block = 760 (20 + 320 + 420)
Sub2 = 240
Sub1 = 160
Start Folder = 20 + 160 + 240 + 760 + 1180
```

I think recursion and os.walk would be key to create the blocks and calculating the block sizes, but I'm struggling to get it running.
The final file should have the Start Folder Block at the beginning.

Appreciate any help.

Thats vaguely my code - the problem is, that the folder block size isn't correct. And I think it would be better to 'push' the data into each folder block as part of the recursion (something which I'm not doing now).

I created an array (lifblocks[]) to which I'm pushing all blocks and finally I'm just writing all blocks inside the array out to a file

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):

        #ignore hidden files and folders (starting with a dot .)
        filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
        dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if not d[0] == '.']

        dirsize = 0

        ''' Folder Block (Block Type 3) '''
        lifblocks.append(LIFBlock(blocktype=3, data=''))
        lifblocks[i].setSize(3735929054) #0xDEADC0DE - Just to test and also to verify that folder size is set correct later
        current_block_index = i #save the index to later adjust the size
        i+=1

        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            size = os.path.getsize(fp)
            size = size + 20 #Add header size

            '''File Block (Block Type 4)'''
            fa = open(fp, "rb")
            file_data = list(fa.read())
            file_data_array = bytearray(file_data)
            fa.close()

            lifblocks.append(LIFBlock(blocktype=4, data=file_data_array))
            i+=1

            dirsize += size
            total_size += size

        dirsize = dirsize + 20 #Add header size
        lifblocks[current_block_index].setSize(dirsize)


        print("\t", dirsize, dirpath)
    print("{0} bytes".format(total_size))

.
.
.
for item in lifblocks:
    test_file.write(item.string())

test_file.close()
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea with `os.walk` to do the folder recursion; can you provide a code example of what you are attempting to do that isn't working?

If you need the start folder at the beginning, this is the `topdown=` optional argument to `os.walk()`

Comment: You are correct you want recursion for this type of function, but you aren't doing recursion here.  os.walk is probably not what you want.  You will probably want to use os.listdir in a recursive function that returns the data structure (header+file data) if passed a file name, and if passed a directory, call itself (recursively) with each element returned from os.listdir(element) collecting all the returns, and returning a data structure with its own header plus all the returned data blocks from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it - this seems to do what I want to do (with Char sizes and not bytes yet)

```
def walkDir(walk_dir):
    #print('walk_dir (absolute) = ' + os.path.abspath(walk_dir))
    fi_content_str = ''
    files_content_str = ''
    subfolders_content_str =''
    fo_dict = {}
    
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir, topdown=False):
        #ignore hidden files and folders (starting with a dot .)
        files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
        subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if not d[0] == '.']
    
        print('--\nroot = ' + root)
        
        files_content_str = ''
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
            file_header_size = file_size + 20
            print('\t- file %s (full path: %s)' % (filename, file_path))

            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                #FS: = Filesize (fixed to 3 digits) including 20 for header, FN = Filename (fixed to 8 chars), FC = File content | Header Size = 20 
                #FS:041FN:abc.txt FC:the file content..... 
                # 3  3  3    8    3 = 20
                fi_content_str = 'FS:{0:0=3d}FN:{1:8.8}FC:{2}'.format(file_header_size, filename, f.read()) #Content of single file
                
            files_content_str = files_content_str + fi_content_str #Content of all files in current folder

        current_dir = os.path.normpath(root).split(os.sep)[-1] #Get the name of the current dir
        
        if files_content_str != '': #Found at least one file
            print '\tFound files: ' + files_content_str
        
        else: # Found a folder without files
            print '\tempty directory (without Files)'
        
        subfolders_content_str = ''
        for subdir in subdirs:
            subfolders_content_str = subfolders_content_str + fo_dict[os.path.join(root, subdir)]
            print('\t- subdirectory '+ os.path.join(root, subdir) +'\t' + subfolders_content_str)
            
        #DS: = Dir Size, DN = Dir Name, DC = Dir Content (either subdirs or files)
        fo_dict[root] = 'DS:{0:0=3d}DN:{1:8.8}DC:{2}'.format(len(files_content_str) + len(subfolders_content_str) + 20 , current_dir, files_content_str + subfolders_content_str)
        #print '\nFOCS: ' + fo_dict[root] +'\n'

    print '\nResult:\n{0}'.format(fo_dict[root])
```